# iOS app crashes without any error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, iphone-4

Well, I'm having this interesting problem.

My iOS app is crashing in iOS Simulator & iPhone 4 but not in iPhone 5.

When it happens, I got this line highlighted:

> 0x1b37aa3:  calll  0x1b37aa8                 ; lookUpMethod + 14

And in Thread 1:

> 0 lookUpMethod
>
> ..............
>
> (some number) UIApplicationMain
>
> (some number) main

I've tried enable NSZombie and putting some logs in `didReceiveMemoryWarning:` and `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` but nothing is logged. I've also put some logs in the middle of my code, but everything get logged pretty well.

How can I know why is this happening?

Comment: Try and add an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but maybe it crashes because you're using a call that is available in iOS5 but not iOS4.  Very much a guess.

Comment: check your deployement target is it 6?

Comment: it may possible that you have declared variable and property in .h file and you have not synthesized that variable in .m file. check out all properties that you have declared in .h file.

Comment: Please list the os name on which you iphone4 is working....

Comment: Krishnabhadra: I did it before and turns out that there is no exception to be handled (?). ——— I'm using a UITextField subclass to validate itself. Here it is: https://github.com/lucasmoreira/LMFormerField — And here is how I'm using it: https://gist.github.com/lucasmoreira/f2f7a8f6b737224cc96a ——— Any ideas? I still have this issue. :/

Answer (score 2):

I've founded the problem. The problem stopped when I remove this line in LMFormerField.m:

```
self.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with a crash that gave no error message. I wasn't using an LMFormerField, but your answer about a delegate reference made me realize that I had some objects with delegate references to my view controller that I needed to set to nil before the view controller was dealloc'd. Once I did that, the crash stopped happening because those objects were no longer trying to access my dealloc'd view controller.